# Wirtinger Inequality: $\int_0^1 f'^2 \geq \pi^2 \int_0^1 f^2 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have a  basic question

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$  map  from  $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ vanishing in $0$ and $1$. I want to prove that

$$\int_0^1 f'^2 \geq \pi^2 \int_0^1 f^2 $$

and to see when we have equality.

Comment: This the proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions

Comment: IL want a proof without Fourier series

Comment: If you want a proof without Fourier series, that's the sort of thing you should specify in your actual question itself (not just the comments) to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that
$$
\int_0^\pi(g'(x)^2-g( x)^2)dx=\int_0^\pi(g'(x)-g(x)\cot x)^2 dx
$$
for $g\in \mathcal{C}^1([0,\pi])$ vanishing at $0$ and $\pi$ and then take $g(x)=f(x/\pi)$

Comment: Dear Norbert, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @user117930 if you are glad with this answer you can accept it by clicking green checkmark under votes count

Comment: I'm new here and i don't anderstand you sorry Norbert

Comment: @user117930, see [this explanation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 2):

If $f(0)=f(1)=$, then $f$ can be expressed as a sine series, i.e.,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin n\pi x.
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\pi a_n\cos n\pi x,
$$
and 
$$
\int_0^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2\,dx=\cdots=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2,
$$
while
$$
\int_0^1 \big(f'(x)\big)^2\,dx=\cdots=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi^2 n^2a_n^2.
$$
Thus
$$
\int_0^1 \big(f'(x)\big)^2 \ge \pi^2\int_0^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2.
$$
Equality for $f(x)=\sin\pi x$.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically asked for a solution with no Fourier series.

Comment: His comment was after my solution.

Comment: Oh? Can you compute $3-2>0$?

Comment: Actually OP's comment was half an hour before this solution. OP should include it in the actual question though.